# Modeling high thermal expansion under fire

Tags: civil-engineering, ansys

I am trying to use Ansys Workbench (Transient Thermal probably coupled with Static Structural analysis) to simulate behavior of a fire protection sleeve. It is used to seal the fire sectors in place where the combustible installations go through walls. Basically, as the temperature goes up, the sleeve expands (its volume goes up rapidly), it cuts out for example a plastic pipe and seals the hole.

How to model this in Ansys?

Comment: this seems awfully broad. You will get better response if you ask more specific questions